# What HTTP status code to return to differenciate resource not found from missing or deleted resource?

Tags: api, api-design

We would like to differentiate (by HTTP status codes) between **correct request but the requested resource is missing or deleted** and **resource not found because of invalid request (URI)**.

For example:

`/api/non-existent-api-because-mispelled-path` which returns `404` because the URI doesn't exist.

And

`/api/my-awesome-api/{id}` which identifier is right but the resource has been deleted.

The reason to differentiate them is due to the monitoring. We are monitoring the API with Azure's *App Insight* which handles and treat 404 as an error. In consequence, our company's dashboard is counting hits to deleted resources as errors, making the metrics inaccurate.

Comment: No. There are 2 categories of Not Found in my case, I want to differentiate between them. App Insight shows all 404 as errors, this is bad, it shows up as 'error/problem' in our company dashboard.

Comment: Perverting HTTP semantics for the sake of a custom and limited dashboard system seems a mediocre argument that, as you guessed, puts you in nobody's land. Is it not possible to customize those filters (say, inspecting the response body or looking for custom HTTP response headers) so that you can differentiate 404 sent by the app server (#1) from 404 sent by your business logic? (#2)

Comment: If you want to respond with a status code that indicates that the resource used to exist but was subsequently deleted, consider `410 Gone` (but using 410 or 403 instead of 404 can leak information). A `204 No Content` would indicate that the resource exists, but that the response doesn't contain a representation of the resource – mostly used to prevent browser navigation after form submission, and has little use in REST APIs. You can't rely on all 404 “errors” being meaningful. I can easily flood your dashboard with useless entries by repeatedly requesting `/api/asdfhjkl`.

Comment: Understood @amon, I have decided to use 410 Gone. I am not concerned with spam requests (we get that from bots from time to time), those are special cases.

Comment: I think @amon's comment is good enough for it to be an answer. I will edit the question and try to shift the focus (204 vs 404) to the real matter (status code for deleted resources).